# Time-driven triggers scope in Google Script

Tags: google-apps-script

UPD:

I have a published application as Spreadsheets addon and a few spreadsheets, that use this addon and execute time driven trigger:

```
ScriptApp.newTrigger("myFunction")
   .timeBased()
   .everyHours(1)
   .create();
```

All works fine, but I'm a little confused, in what scope does this trigger work?

Since this is a published addon, the script is one and the time driven function is also one, right? As Diego said: "It works with the user scopes of the user who initiated the trigger". Okay, but what about spreadsheets?

I need to write (if trigger sees only this spreadsheet):

```
function myFunction(){
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
}
```

Or (if it runs without binding to a specific spreadsheet):

```
function myFunction(){
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('<some id>');
}
```

In other words, when I set the trigger, do I set it only for the current document or for all?

Thanks!

Comment: Did you read documentation? https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable#installable_triggers_in_add-ons

Comment: Yes, I read. But I didn't find any info about scopes of time-driven triggers.

Comment: It mentions the trigger is for the user, only in their document that it is added into. Is that not your question?

Comment: I reformulated the question, look, please

Comment: it runs only in the document it is installed in. So if you need to read a reference spreadsheet, you would use `openById` to access that one. If you need the sheet the add-on was installed in, use `getActive`

Comment: Thanks, your answer helped me

Answer (score 1):

It works with the user scopes of the user who initiated the trigger. Here's how you can check:

1. Create a User property value `i` and set it to zero
2. In a new function, get the user property `i`, write it to a sheet, increment `i` and save it back to the property.
3. Create a trigger so that function runs every minute.
4. View the spreadsheet as a different user.
5. As the different user, repeat steps 1 & 2 to see that now `i` has started again from zero, but the 1-minute trigger is still iterating the original `i` value (because the different user can't access the first user's properties).

Here's the code:

```
function getAndPrintUserProperty() {
  var userProperties = PropertiesService.getUserProperties();
  var i = userProperties.getProperty("i");
  i++;
  SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("Sheet1").appendRow([i]);
  userProperties.setProperty("i", i);
}

function addUserProperty() {
  PropertiesService.getUserProperties().setProperty("i", 0);
}
```

Comment: If it works with the user scope, if one user has two documents, will this trigger work with both of them? Or in this case: one time-trigger **for one user and one document**?

Comment: I don't think I fully understand your question. The trigger just executes a function, so if the user has already granted permissions, then you can execute any function and thus any chain of functions, which can access any document the user has granted access to.

Comment: I reformulated the question, look, please